# CKasset File Size limit for CloudKit

Tags: ios, file-upload, limit, cloudkit, ckasset

Hi we want to upload large size video files to CloudKit. Are there any file size limit on CKAsset ? there is a link that mentions that the size limit is 15 mb but that cannot be correct since we tried uploading a 300MB video and it was successfully uploaded. Also, the doc is for cloud kit web services, so does that mean that though cloud kit JS only 15mb asset can be uploaded or downloaded ?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/PropertyMetrics/PropertyMetrics.html

Comment: I know this question is old, but were you able to confirm that you could upload a `CKAsset` with the Web Services API that is larger than **15MB**?

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 1MB for CKRecord, but CKAsset is not affected by this limit, according to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord)...

> To ensure the speed of fetching and saving records, the data stored by
>   a record must not exceed 1 MB. Assets do not count against this limit
>   but all other data types do.

Comment: Yes, but the JS doc has this limit mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any link citing a maximum asset size; however, there are limits for **total** storage and transfer of all assets in the container. [this](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/) Apple page has a calculator that shows total asset storage limits based on the number of users. You can see your actual usage on the Cloudkit dashboard's usage page.

It seems to me there's no hard size limit per asset, as long as you stay under your total Asset Storage and transfer limits. I wouldn't get too hung up on what the page you cited said about 15mb since you've already proven that wrong. It certainly wouldn't be the first Apple documentation page that has wrong info. Heck, it's not even the only `CloudKit` documentation page with wrong info.